# Problem with Socket.BeginConnect in MonoTouch 4.01 (was OK in 3.2.6)

Tags: sockets, xamarin.ios

I've got some extensive .Net socket code that I have been using in MonoTouch 3.x with no problems. Beginning with MonoTouch 4.00, my Socket.BeginConnect calls no longer fire their supplied callbacks.

It's moderately painful to switch between MonoTouch 3.x and 4.x on my development machine here so I haven't performed an extensive comparison of the socket object state between the two yet, but I was wondering if anybody had had similar issues?

Will be back to edit this when I have more information.

Comment: Definitely fixed in MonoTouch 4.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with MonoTouch 4.0, we're working on a fix and will have a 4.0.2 out to address this soon.