# WebClient and SOAP calls lock up in MonoTouch 4.0.0 and 4.0.1. Works in 3.2.6. Demo inside. What's causing it?

Tags: xamarin.ios

My app is making heavy use of webservice calls. Lately, some of the calls got stuck. After playing around I figured out that it

- happens mostly for release builds
- happens in the Simulator AND on the device (iPad, iOS 4.3)
- happens more often on iPad 1 than on iPad 2
- it is not limited to web services an SOAP but also affects the System.Net.WebClient
- does not affest [NSString stringWithContentsOfUrl:] if invoked manually, since not bound

The effect is that the CPU load of the device drops to zero. memory is stable (in my demo project 8.5MB). If I put Console.WriteLines() everywhere, I can see that the code is stuck inside one of the WebClient.Download*() methods.

The code below demonstrates that (if built RELEASE with MT 4.0.1, LLVM off or on does not matter) downloading a file from the web over and over again fails sometimes right away on the first try, sometimes after 10 times, sometimes after around 30 downloads.
It is totally random. If you think it works, kill the app and restart it and eventually it will hang.

When building the same using MT 3.2.6, the downloading goes on all day without issues. It is impossible to break it.

MONO installed is the latest available version.

Can somebody from the MT team comment on it?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace iOSTest
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args);
        }
    }

    // The name AppDelegate is referenced in the MainWindow.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
    private Thread oThread;
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // Make a release build and run on iPad 1 with iOS 4.3.2.
            // Fails after downloading between 1 time and 30 times on MT 4.0.1.
            // It is possible that it seems to work. Then just kill the app and restart and suddenly the effect
            // will become visible. If you watch it with Instruments, CPU suddenly drops to zero. The app then is
            // stuck somewhere inside WebClient. After about 10 minutes, an exception will be thrown (timeout).
            // Never fails on MT 3.2.6
            Console.WriteLine(MonoTouch.Constants.Version);

            // A label that counts how often we downloaded.
            UILabel oLbl = new UILabel(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(40, 100, 150, 30));
            window.AddSubview(oLbl);

            // This thread downloads the same file over and over again.
            // The thread is not required to demonstrate the issue. The same problem occurs
            // if the download is running on the main thread.
            this.oThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                using(var oPool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    while(true)
                    {
                        // Setup webclient and download a file from my website (around 2.4 MB)
                        WebClient oClient = new WebClient();
```

// It would be nice to hange it to your own URL to save me from all the traffic.
oClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.wildsau.net/image.axd?picture=2011%2f4%2fDSC05178.JPG"), Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "test.jpg"));

```
                        // Increase counter and update label.
                        i++;
                        this.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate { oLbl.Text = i.ToString(); });
                        Console.WriteLine("Done " + i + " times.");
                    }
                }
            });

            // Have a button that starts the action.
            UIButton oBtn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            oBtn.SetTitle("Download", UIControlState.Normal);
            oBtn.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(40, 40, 150, 30);
            oBtn.TouchUpInside += delegate(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                this.oThread.Start();
            };
            window.AddSubview(oBtn);
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }

        // This method is required in iPhoneOS 3.0
        public override void OnActivated (UIApplication application)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Talked to Geoff yesterday. Looks like there is an issue in 4.0.0 and 4.0.1. It will be fixed in 4.0.2. A couple of network issues seem to have been introduced.

Comment: Yeah, sounds similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803114/problem-with-socket-beginconnect-in-monotouch-4-01-was-ok-in-3-2-6

Comment: Still not working in 4.0.5. Haven't tried alpha 4.1...

Comment: I am just trying it with MT 4.0.4.1 and MonoDevelop 2.8 Alpha and I have downloaded my test file 100 times so far without crash. But I'm running on iPad 2 with iOS 5 Beta 5. It crashes immediately on my iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3 :-( I will give 4.1 beta and 4.9 alpha a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promised to be fixed by Xamarin in the next major release. Still does not work in 4.0.4 though.

Comment: It finally seeems to be fixed in 4.1! Ihave tested it successfully on my iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3. The funny thing is: on iOS 5 Beta 5, even the 4.0.4.1 works, but still crashes with iOS 4.3. Hooray!

Answer (score 1):

From Gonzalo-

When the problem occurs, "kicking" the threadpool by adding another
work item will make the problem go away.

Something like this (not tested or compiled ;-) should do:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer (AddMe);
...
    WebClient wc = new WebClient ();
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    timer.Change (0, 500); // Trigger it now and every 500ms
    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(uri);
    timer.Change (Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
....
    static void AddMe (object state)
    {
     // Empty.
    }
```

#

Works 100% of the time - for me at least - YMMV. And it did, once we put the code under stress (Lots of files to download) it stalled again. Just heard from MT that 4.0.6 will have *the* fix in it. Should see it later this week!

Comment: The above code was just a workaround while we release the fix. The real fix was pushed to Mono a few days ago and will be in the upcoming MonoTouch version (>4.0.5).